# Add and remove active class to multiple ids automatically in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently have the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="sat0" class="sat"></div>
<div id="sat1" class="sat"></div>
<div id="sat2" class="sat"></div>
<div id="sat3" class="sat"></div>
<div id="sat4" class="sat"></div>
<div id="sat5" class="sat"></div>
<div id="sat6" class="sat"></div>
<div id="sat7" class="sat"></div>
<div id="sat8" class="sat"></div>
<div id="sat9" class="sat"></div>
<div id="sat10" class="sat"></div>
<div id="sat11" class="sat"></div>
</div>
```

I want the class="active" added to id="sat0" and id="sat6" on page load. Then a second later the active class should be remove from both and be added to the two next ones so id="sat1" and id="sat7". It should loop endlessly, so when gets to id="sat5" and id="sat11" the next would be "id=sat6" and id="sat0".

Currently using the following javascript.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#sat0").addClass("active");
      $("#sat6").addClass("active");
      setTimeout(autoAddClass, 1200);
});

function autoAddClass(){
  var next = $(".active").removeClass("active").next();
  if(next.length)
      $(next).addClass('active');
  else
  $("#sat0").addClass("active");
  $("#sat6").addClass("active");
  setTimeout(autoAddClass, 1200);
}
</script>
```

It acts rather chaotically. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason you seem to get chaotic behavior is that you're always adding `active` back to `#sat6`, because you need to use a block in your `else` (really, I recommend always using blocks with control-flow statements) so the `#sat6` part is conditional:

```
function autoAddClass(){
    var next = $(".active").removeClass("active").next();
    if(next.length) {
      $(next).addClass('active');
    } else {
        $("#sat0").addClass("active");
        $("#sat6").addClass("active");
    }
    setTimeout(autoAddClass, 1200);
}
```

Updated example:

```js
function autoAddClass(){
    var next = $(".active").removeClass("active").next();
    if(next.length) {
        $(next).addClass('active');
    } else {
        $("#sat0").addClass("active");
        $("#sat6").addClass("active");
    }
    setTimeout(autoAddClass, 1200);
}
autoAddClass();
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="sat0" class="sat">0</div>
<div id="sat1" class="sat">1</div>
<div id="sat2" class="sat">2</div>
<div id="sat3" class="sat">3</div>
<div id="sat4" class="sat">4</div>
<div id="sat5" class="sat">5</div>
<div id="sat6" class="sat">6</div>
<div id="sat7" class="sat">7</div>
<div id="sat8" class="sat">8</div>
<div id="sat9" class="sat">9</div>
<div id="sat10" class="sat">10</div>
<div id="sat11" class="sat">11</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But another reason would be that the top sequence (starting with `#sat0`) continues longer than the other; you might want `if (next.length == 2)` instead of just `if (next.length)`:

```js
function autoAddClass(){
    var next = $(".active").removeClass("active").next();
    if(next.length == 2) {
        $(next).addClass('active');
    } else {
        $("#sat0").addClass("active");
        $("#sat6").addClass("active");
    }
    setTimeout(autoAddClass, 1200);
}
autoAddClass();
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="sat0" class="sat">0</div>
<div id="sat1" class="sat">1</div>
<div id="sat2" class="sat">2</div>
<div id="sat3" class="sat">3</div>
<div id="sat4" class="sat">4</div>
<div id="sat5" class="sat">5</div>
<div id="sat6" class="sat">6</div>
<div id="sat7" class="sat">7</div>
<div id="sat8" class="sat">8</div>
<div id="sat9" class="sat">9</div>
<div id="sat10" class="sat">10</div>
<div id="sat11" class="sat">11</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

BTW, if you want to make it easier to add/remove divs, you don't need any of those `id="..."`; just use `$(".sat:nth-child(1)")` and `$(".sat:nth-child(7)")` (or if you have other elements in there, `$(".sat:eq(0)")` and `$(".sat:eq(6)")`) to start with:

```js
function autoAddClass(){
    var next = $(".active").removeClass("active").next();
    if(next.length == 2) {
        $(next).addClass('active');
    } else {
        $(".sat:nth-child(1)").addClass("active");
        $(".sat:nth-child(7)").addClass("active");
    }
    setTimeout(autoAddClass, 1200);
}
autoAddClass();
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="sat">0</div>
<div class="sat">1</div>
<div class="sat">2</div>
<div class="sat">3</div>
<div class="sat">4</div>
<div class="sat">5</div>
<div class="sat">6</div>
<div class="sat">7</div>
<div class="sat">8</div>
<div class="sat">9</div>
<div class="sat">10</div>
<div class="sat">11</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(If you have multiple `.wrapper` that you're doing this in, you'll have to adjust things a bit to work within them individually...)

Comment: Added a second reason for apparent chaos as well, and live examples. :-)

Comment: I used same method except `if (next.length > 1)`. Good answer.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly. In your code snippet, it appears to be working as expected which is great, but in my local staging site example while working much better is still skipping some of the items. But so must be something else in my code causing the issue. Going to investigate a little more than will mark this as correct and will note what else might have been the issue for others as well. Thanks so much! As for the ids those are added for another part of the site functionality not noted in this Stack Overflow.